# unable to connect to remote SQL Server from win server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008

I have setup an APP server on Win Server 2008 R2 and my SQL server( SQL server 2008 R2)  on a separate server Windows Vista. When I host my ASP.net application on App server and trying to connect to SQL server it doesnt connect. Not sure if I have missed some settings.  Could you please suggest if there are any settings that I need to make for this to work.

thanks in advance
Sai

Comment: you might want to give some more details about your configs & settings

Comment: Please provide the error message and code depicting how you connecting with the SQL server?

Comment: Connection string is taken from web.config file and I use Ent lib 4.0 to connect to sql server. I'm unable to get the error displayed. I will retry by changing the code and publish it again and capture the error.

Answer (score 0):

The Vista firewall might be blocking.  Follow this:

http://techpint.com/programming/error-26-%E2%80%93-error-locating-serverinstance-specified-sql-server